# checking new WiFi network continuously without timer/schedule (Android)

Tags: android, android-wifi, connectivity, wifimanager

One of the function of my app is to select a preferred network in background, like what [Wifi Prioritizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.za.flash.wifiprioritizer&hl=zh_TW) does, but I don't want to scan Wifi network periodically with timer/schedule. I would like to trigger WiFi switching related actions with events.

I tried to register [SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION), but I can't find any Wifi scan action triggering the event. I also looked over WifiManager and ConnectivityManager, but I can't find any related event.

Assume that I have already connected to a Wifi network, is there any events/ways to keep the check on other(new/old) WiFi networks continuously in background.

p.s. It is my first question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

First we need following permission in order to access network state. Add following permission to your **Manifest** file.

Permissions required to access **Network state** and **Wifi**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Create class which extends **Broadcast Receiver** and override methods

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;


public class Check_Connectivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    if(isConnected){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}}
```

Comment: Okay, but what event should I register in order to trigger the action inside onReceive?